# Why do Pardot form handler responses randomly take so long for new submitters?

Tags: salesforce, pardot

On a Gatsby React site we are submitting form data to Pardot via a regular `form` element with the form handler as the form's `action`. This works well and data is submitted every time. However, we've noticed a pattern in which submitting a form in a new incognito window will sometimes result in a Pardot response which takes significantly longer, usually 11-14 seconds although occasionally up to 44 seconds. This is compared with a normal response time of under 1 second. Although Pardot responds with a 302 redirect, we can verify the response time in the network tab:

Here is a normal response:
[image: Normal response time]
And here is an abnormally long response:
[image: Long response time]

Behavior appears inconsistent between users, making it difficult to pin down a pattern. When I test the form I never get the long response time unless I specifically test with "test@test.com", which led me to believe it was related to user tracking, but other users have reported experiencing the issue with other emails and not experiencing the issue even when using "test@test.com".

Here is a table with a series of tests done by two users. Personal information removed for obvious reasons:

| # | Email | Response Time | Device | Person | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test@test.com | 8.82s | Mac | Person A | 4:00 PM |
| 2 | personal email | 594.78 ms | Mac | Person A | 4:00 PM |
| 3 | cejaj37151@kkoup.com | 1.19 s | Mac | Person A | 4:00 PM |
| 4 | test@our domain | 10.84 s | Mac | Person A | 4:00 PM |
| 5 | tester@our domain | 592.04 ms | Windows | Person A | 4:00 PM |
| 6 | tester4@gmail.com | 868.29 ms | Windows | Person A | 4:00 PM |
| 7 | tester5@our domain | 805.62 ms | old mac | Person A | 5:00 PM |
| 8 | test345@gmail.com | 1.22 s | old mac | Person A | 5:00 PM |
| 9 | personal email | 479.94 ms | Android | Person A | 5:00 PM |
| 10 | website@our domain | 665.45 ms | Android | Person A | 5:00 PM |
| 11 | test@our domain | 44.26 s | Mac | Person A | 8:32 AM |
| 12 | personal email | 1.08 s | Mac | Person A | 8:43 AM |
| 13 | test@test.com | 11.86 s | Android | Person A | 9:10 AM |
| 14 | test@test.com | 400.18ms | Mac-chrome | Person B | 8:54 AM |
| 15 | test@test.com | 11.77s | Mac-incognito | Person B | 8:57 AM |
| 16 | test@test.com | 551.97ms | Mac-incognito | Person B | 9:00 AM |
| 17 | test@test.com | 409.10 ms | Mac-chrome | Person B | 9:15 AM |
| 18 | personal email | 14.72 s | Mac-chrome | Person B | 9:21 AM |
| 19 | test@test.com | 11.63 s | Android | Person A | 9:15 AM |
| 20 | test@test.com | 15.24 s | Mac-chrome | Person B | 9:31 AM |
| 21 | personal email | 822.38 ms | Mac | Person A | 9:31 AM |
| 22 | personal email | 313.3 ms | iPhone-safari | Person B | 10:50 AM |
| 23 | personal email | 58.5 ms | iPhone-safari | Person B | 10:56 AM |
| 24 | test@test.com | 66 ms | iPhone-safari | Person B | 11:01 AM |
| 25 | test@test.com | 123.9 ms | iPhone-safari | Person B | 11:03 AM |
| 26 | personal email | 73.8 ms | iPhone-safari | Person B | 11:08 AM |
| 27 | test@test.com | 49.9 ms | iPhone-safari | Person B | 11:13 AM |
| 28 | test@test.com | 56 ms | iPhone-safari | Person B | 11:16 AM |
| 29 | n@test.test | 56.5 ms | iPhone-safari | Person B | 11:20 AM |
| 30 | test100@test.com | 186.1 ms | Mac-safari | Person B | 12:38 PM |
| 31 | test100@test.com | 44 ms | Mac-safari | Person B | 12:41 PM |
| 32 | name@test.com | 158.1 ms | Mac-safari | Person B | 12:50 PM |
| 33 | test20@gmail.com | 80.1 ms | Mac-safari | Person B | 12:56 PM |
| 34 | test21@our domain | 74.1 ms | Mac-safari | Person B | 12:58 PM |
| 35 | test@our domain | 16.31 s | Mac-Chrome | Person B | 4:45 PM |
| 36 | test@our domain | 321.30 ms | Mac-Chrome | Person B | 4:51 PM |
| 37 | test@our domain | 577.84 ms | Mac-Chrome | Person B | 4:53 PM |
| 38 | test@our domain | 338.49 ms | Mac-Chrome | Person B | 4:54 PM |
| 39 | personal email | 3.95 s | Mac-Chrome | Person B | 4:56 PM |

I can't find any pattern here. Could it be affected by nearest server? User tracking? Throttling? This issue has persisted since before the site went live, so it's not likely related to traffic.